# Ansible Print IOS output on string match

Tags: ansible, cisco-ios

I'm trying to use Ansible to hit a bunch (100+) Cisco Catalyst switches and check if they have a certain line card installed. Via SSH, this can be done with the "sh mod" command. I want to parse the output of that command in a playbook and then show the output of the command if a certain string matches. Right now with the playbook below I get the following error:

> fatal: [redacted-hostname]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The
>   conditional check 'showmod | search(\"4548\")' failed. The error was:
>   Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if showmod |
>   search(\"4548\") %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): expected
>   string or buffer\n\nThe error appears to have been in
>   '/etc/ansible/playbooks/linecard-4548.yaml': line 22, column 5, but
>   may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax
>   problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - debug:
>   \"msg='4548 Card Found'\"\n    ^ here\n"}

Current playbook code:

```
---
- hosts: redacted-hostname
  gather_facts: yes
  connection: local

  tasks:

  - name: SYS | Define provider
    set_fact:
      provider:
        host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}" 
        username: redacted-user
        password: redacted-password

  - name: IOS | Get Module List
    ios_command:
      provider: "{{ provider }}"
      commands:
          - sh mod | inc 4548
    register: showmod

  - debug: "msg='4548 Card Found'"
    when: showmod.stdout | search("/4548/")
```

I've tried the `when` in the debug with and without the `.stdout` to no avail. I've done some research and the error I'm getting usually occurs when, in my case, `showmod` is undefined but it definitely is. If I replace the debug with the following snippet, the playbook runs fine but of course it'll print the output for every switch which isn't what I want.

```
  - name: IOS | Show Output
    debug:
      var: showmod
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ios_command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ios_command_module.html) returns `stdout` as list and `stdout_lines` as list of lists (whereas `command` module return `stdout` as string and `stdout_lines` as list).

So in your case, you may want to try:

```
- debug: "msg='4548 Card Found'"
  when: showmod.stdout | join(" ") | search("/4548/")
```